# InputMismatch error trying to take integer as user input

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, collections

I am trying to take an integer as user input and store it in a list until the user hits 'q'. At the moment the user inputs 'q', the loop gets terminated.

The code is showing an `InputMismatch` error:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class SampleArrayList {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s;
        int n;
        
        List<Integer> array = new ArrayList();
        
        while (true) {
            n = sc.nextInt();
            s = sc.nextLine();
            if (s.equals("q")) {
                break;
            } else {
                array.add(n);
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(array);
        System.out.println(array);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: @tquadrat if this code is right then why its showing an InputMismatch Error?

Comment: When the `InputMismatchError` is your problem, you should write that in your question! We do not analyse your code to find out what might be probably wrong – we look what might have caused the described error condition. No error description, no solution attempt!

Comment: `while(true) if(sc.hasNextInt()) array.add(sc.nextInt()); else if(sc.nextLine().equals("q")) break;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this,

Inside your while loop to get input for a string use,

```
s = sc.next();
```

Instead of `sc.nextLine();`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to implement it like the example below?

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s;

        List<Integer> array = new ArrayList();
        while (true) {
            s = sc.nextLine();
            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                break;
            }
            int num = Integer.parseInt(s);
            array.add(num);
        }

        Collections.sort(array);
        System.out.println(array);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Yes. But it shows an error msg (InputMismatchError)

Comment: ~~~java
n = sc.nextInt();
s = sc.nextLine();
~~~

Since it is implemented to receive input twice as above, both numbers and string line values must be entered. 
When entering Q, you will initially ride sc.nextInt(), and only numeric values can be input, resulting in InputMatchException.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `q` is trying to be stored as an `int`, so this should work:

All numbers stored as a `String` can be parsed as an `int` with the `parseInt()` method.

```
s = sc.nextLine();

if (!s.equals("q"))
{

    array.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
}
else
{
    break;
}
```